# Kong api gateway return 404 not found instead message : no route and no API found with those values

Tags: api-gateway, kong

I used route http://base_url/apis/

but when i try to another url example http://base_url/tests/

it returns

```
{"message":"no route and no API found with those values"}
```

but i want get 404 not found when access urls that i don't specify

how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but it should be possible to create a "catch all" route with a low `regex_priority` which you then route to a "default backend" kind of service which then would answer with whatever you define it to return, e.g. 404, "not found".

This will only work with Kong 0.13.x+ or Kong 1.0+; I don't think that there is something corresponding for earlier versions using the `/apis` API of the Kong management API.